# Run GlassFish 3.1.1 in the same way NetBeans does

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3

I would like to run GlassFish 3.1.1 from the command line such that it will stop when I close the command line window. NetBeans does something like this, because when it is closed, any running GlassFish instance is also closed.

I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: use the -v option. Example:

`asadmin start-domain -v`

This causes all log output to be shown in stdout and terminates on CTRL-C or the window closing.

*(For others looking for admin documentation, here's the [GlassFish Product Documentation](http://glassfish.java.net/docs/), esp. the Administration Guide.)*

Answer (score 0):

or

```
asadmin stop-domain
```

will also stop it.